# Spring data Cassandra 2.0 Select BLOB column returns incorrect ByteBuffer data

Tags: cassandra, blob, bytebuffer, spring-data-cassandra

Context: Spring data cassandra official 1.0.2.RELEASE from Maven Central repo, CQL3, cassandra 2.0, datastax driver 2.0.4

Background: The cassandra blob data type is mapped to a Java ByteBuffer.

The sample code below demonstrates that you won't retrieve the correct bytes using select next to an equivalent insert. The data actually retrieved is prefixed by numerous garbage bytes that actually looks like a serialization of the entire row.
This [older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282361/serializing-java-objects-to-cassandra-1-2-via-bytebuffer-cql-3) relating to Cassandra 1.2 suggested that we may have to start at ByteBuffer.arrayOffset() of length ByteBuffer.remaining(), but a the arrayOffset value is actually 0.

I discovered a spring-data-cassandra 2.0.0. SNAPSHOT but the CassandraOperations API is much different, and its package name too: org.springdata... versus org.springframework...

Help in fixing this will be much welcome.

In the mean time it looks like I have to encode/decode Base64 my binary data to/from a text data type column.

--- here is the simple table CQL meta data I use -------------

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  id text,
  age int,
  name text,
  pict blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ;
```

--- follows the simple data object mapped to a CQL table ---

```
package org.spring.cassandra.example; 
 
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKey; 
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table; 
 
@Table 
public class Person { 
 
 @PrimaryKey 
 private String id; 
 
 private int age; 
 private String name; 
 private ByteBuffer pict; 
 
 public Person(String id, int age, String name, ByteBuffer pict) { 
  this.id = id; this.name = name; this.age = age; this.pict = pict;
 } 
 
 public String getId() { return id; } 
 public String getName() { return name; } 
 public int getAge() { return age; } 
 public ByteBuffer getPict() { return pict; } 
     
 } 
 
}
```

--- and the plain java application code that simply inserts and retrieves a person object --

```
package org.spring.cassandra.example;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraOperations;

import com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Row;
import com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.QueryBuilder;
import com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Select;

public class CassandraApp {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(CassandraApp.class);

    public static String hexDump(ByteBuffer bb) {
        char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
        bb.rewind();
        char[] hexChars = new char[bb.limit() * 2];
        for ( int j = 0; j < bb.limit(); j++ ) {
            int v = bb.get() & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        bb.rewind();
        return new String(hexChars);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app-context.xml");

        try {

            CassandraOperations cassandraOps = applicationContext.getBean(
                    "cassandraTemplate", CassandraOperations.class);

            cassandraOps.truncate("person");
            // prepare data
            byte[] ba = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, (byte) 0xAA, (byte) 0xCC, (byte) 0xFF };
            ByteBuffer myPict = ByteBuffer.wrap(ba);
            String myId = "1234567890";
            String myName = "mickey";
            int myAge = 50;
            
            logger.info("We try id=" + myId + ", name=" + myName + ", age=" + myAge +", pict=" + hexDump(myPict));
            
            cassandraOps.insert(new Person(myId, myAge, myName, myPict ));

            Select s = QueryBuilder.select("id","name","age","pict").from("person");
            s.where(QueryBuilder.eq("id", myId));

            ResultSet rs = cassandraOps.query(s);
            Row r = rs.one();
            
            logger.info("We got id=" + r.getString(0) + ", name=" + r.getString(1) + ", age=" + r.getInt(2) +", pict=" + hexDump(r.getBytes(3)));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

--- assuming you have configured a simple Spring project for cassandra
as explained at http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-cassandra/

The actual execution yields:

[main] INFO org.spring.cassandra.example.CassandraApp - We try id=1234567890, name=mickey, age=50, pict= **0001020304051122334455AACCFF**

[main] INFO org.spring.cassandra.example.CassandraApp - We got id=1234567890, name=mickey, age=50, pict=8200000800000073000000020000000100000004000A6D796B657973706163650006706572736F6E00026964000D00046E616D65000D000361676500090004706963740003000000010000000A31323334353637383930000000066D69636B657900000004000000320000000E **0001020304051122334455AACCFF**

although the insert looks correct in the database itself, as seen from cqlsh command line:

```
cqlsh:mykeyspace> select * from person;

 id         | age | name   | pict
------------+-----+--------+--------------------------------
 1234567890 |  50 | mickey | 0x0001020304051122334455aaccff

(1 rows)
```

Comment: Please enter an issue for this at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS.  Further, if you could fork the repo at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra, create a failing test, and send a pull request, that would really help.

Comment: "I discovered a spring-data-cassandra 2.0.0. SNAPSHOT but the
CassandraOperations API is much different, and its package name
too: org.springdata... versus org.springframework..."

The official Spring Data Cassandra project is at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra.  Any other Cassandra projects are not considered part of the official Spring Data umbrella.  I'm sorry this confusion exists.

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same problem but have fortunately found a solution.
The problem is that ByteBuffer use is confusing.  Try doing something like:

```
ByteBuffer bb = resultSet.one().getBytes("column_name");
byte[] data = new byte[bb.remaining()];
bb.get(data);
```

Thanks to Sylvain's for this suggestion here: http://grokbase.com/t/cassandra/user/134brvqzd3/blobs-in-cql

Comment: Indeed that works when we scope down to the 'remaining()' part of the byte buffer. The conclusion is that object mapping with blobs is buggy and you must use result sets as alternative as you describe, else restrict your object mappings to use strings and inject the string<>hex-or_B64 conversion into your object getters/setters/constructors... why I did in anticipation for the next release where this could be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Give a look at the [Bytes](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/Bytes.html) class of the Datastax Java Driver, it provides what you need to encode/decode your data.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197685/how-can-i-store-objects-in-cassandra/25198590#25198590) I wrote an usage example.

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: Thanks but -- if I read and understand well -- the bytes class just facilitates conversion from/to hex-encoded strings, in essence allowing to transparently store ByteBuffers as text in cassandra, hence a substitution for the base64 encoding I cited that would increase the binary blob size by 33% against 100% with hex encoding.  In essence, this does not solve the root problem but circumvents it.